# How to fix get users in posts?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm write project for learning Angular. My project displays posts. I want to output users in table. I have to use method in my template (for example getUser(id)). But it works strange (Usernames are displayed as "Bret,,,,,,,,, ,Antonette,,,,,,,, ,,Samantha,,,,,,," ect). How to fix this problem?

All project [posts project](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-lake-fhml5?file=/src/app/posts/posts.component.ts)

posts.component.ts:

```
getUsername(id: any) {
    return this.users.map((us: any) => {
      return us.id == id ? us.username : "";
    });
  }
```

posts.component.html:

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 10%;" />
    <col style="width: 15%;" />
    <col style="width: 75%;" />
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let column of columns">{{ column.title }}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr [formGroup]="form">
      <th *ngFor="let column of columns">
        <ng-container *ngIf="column.filterKey">
          <input type="text" [formControlName]="column.filterKey" />
        </ng-container>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of posts">
            <td>{{ item.userId }}</td>
            <td>
                {{ getUsername(item.userId) }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <a [routerLink]="['/posts', item.id]">{{ item.title | titlecase }}</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because your `getUsername` function returns `["Bret","","","","Antonette", "", ""]`. You need to find only the user you're looking for, and return their name :

```
getUsername(id: any) {
    return this.users
        .find((us: any) => us.id == id)
        .username;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. For the not-matched users, it's inserting an empty string.

If It possible to request a user by unknown id, for which matched user can not be found, use this example

```
getUsername(id: any) {
    return this.users
        .find((us: any) => us.id === id)?.username || '';
     
}
```

Otherwise

```
getUsername(id: any) {
    return this.users
        .find((us: any) => us.id === id)
        .username;
}
```